# sqlite3.OperationnalError: near "TEXT": syntax error

Tags: sqlite, python-3.x

`print msg` returns `['2013-07-08 10','temperature','kitchen','22.5']`

When I run this code :

```
data="bdd.sq3"
conn=sqlite3.connect(data)
cur=conn.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temperature (date TEXT, type TEXT, zone TEXT, value REAL)")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO temperature (date TEXT, type TEXT, zone TEXT, value REAL) VALUES(?,?,?,?)",(msg))
```

I have this error :

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO temperature (date TEXT, type TEXT, zone TEXT, value REAL) VALUES(?,?,?,?)",(msg))    
sqlite3.OperationnalError: near "TEXT": syntax error
```

But I can’t see what’s wrong. I use similar code in other program and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need those `TEXT` tags when inserting in your database. You only use that when creating the database table. Just make sure that the values you're inserting in the database are the same type as you've given when creating the table.

Comment: Thanks. I have understand what was my problem : I used an old database with the same table names but not the same columns. Since I have removed the old database a the ew has been created and it works.